# Gradient over an absolute element

Tags: css, positioning, gradient

I would like to add a gradient layer to the sides of my slider.

So i have this code:

```
<div>
    <div id="gradientsx">
    </div>
    <ul class="slider">
        <li>item 1</li>
        [...]
    </ul>
    <div id="gradientdx">
    </div>
</div>
```

.gradientsx has a background with the gradient and his postision is absolute. But also the `<ul>` must have an absolute position (to permit the sliding), so the grandient in gradientsx became invisible. How can I fix this?

Here's the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/tPMuA/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `z-index` to force the shadow-div on top of the items. But beware, it may also block mouse-events if it's on top of the items. Not sure if this is a problem, though, because I can't find out from that fiddle what the slider is going to look like.

http://jsfiddle.net/tPMuA/7/

Comment: Other question: is possible to achieve the same effect with CSS3?

Comment: You'd better ask that as a new question. It will become an unreadable mess if we do that in the comments and a new question will be more visible to other users.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13331011/1760030